# Visual Studio Code ignoring text mate theme in settings.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

So I have a color theme set as Github Dark default right now, before I had it set as Monokai pro where I went into Setting.json and change some settings for textmate scopes and change their colors, it worked when I had the previous theme setup but when I changed the theme the settings don't take effect and uses the themes default color scheme. I don't know why that's happening.
Like I have this in my settings.json for the color of a function name
[image]
[image]
But instead I don't see the changes in this method in one of my java files. It should show up as green for the function call but instead it shows up as purple. And it should show purple Variable names but it's gray.
[image]

Comment: Can you share your settings.json

Comment: Can you also share some screenshots showing which part of syntax highlighting is not working? Thanks

Comment: Hi, I will update the question right now.